# Python script uses 100% CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey I was working with python. In my python file I just have 2 lines like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env
print("hello")
```

and I make my .py file executable and run it(./hello.py) on ubuntu server.
With "top" command, i listed all processes.
hello.py uses 100% CPU.
Why it use 100% CPU(Server has 512MB 1 CPU)

Comment: Not sure if it'll fix your cpu consumption problem, but the shebang needs `python`, i.e. add python to the header: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: When I write #!/usr/bin/env python it says "/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory"

Comment: Check what `which python` returns. Then try changing that line to use that python version, perhaps it needs to be something like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Yes I did it like that and it works. Thanks...

Comment: of course, cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your incorrect shebang line of

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

causes the system to launch `/usr/bin/env` to handle the script, as follows:

```
/usr/bin/env ./hello.py
```

`/usr/bin/env` treats the first argument not containing `=` and not starting with `-` as a program to run, so it tries to launch `./hello.py`. Due to the incorrect shebang line, this once again runs

```
/usr/bin/env ./hello.py
```

It's an infinite loop.